# Xcode after compiling program shows only lldb, but no answers, how to change it?

Tags: c++, xcode, lldb

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;
    int main () {

    double x=0.2,skait,vard1,vard2,E;


    cout<<"Results"<<endl;
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        E=exp(x+2);
        skait=log((2*x*x)+(3*E));
        vard1=abs(sin(2*x)-(8*x*x*x));
        vard2=sin(x*x);
        cout<<(skait/(vard1+vard2))<<endl;
        x=x+0.08;
    }
    return 0;
```

So this was my lab project, but after compiling the code i get `(lldb)` message and nothing else.
How to view the answer or change the preferences so that i'd never see that error again?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p5ZT.jpg) - The error

Comment: What do you mean by "get (lldb) message"?

Comment: I added a link for you to view the screenshot of the error.

Comment: I don't know about Xcode, but do you possibly have a breakpoint set in the loop? What happens if you don't run in the debugger, or even try to run your program from a command-line terminal?

Comment: It seems that i had set a breakpoint indeed. Thank you Joachim.